# How to use assertRaises() to rise an error

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am learning how to unit test with unittest in Python.
What I am trying to do is to raise a ValueError in the case a negative turn number, and display a message, such as 'turn cannot be negative'.

the code I have written so far is the following:

```
import unittest
from canvas import Game


class TestPlayer1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        # Game objects
        self.game_turn_0 = Game()
        self.game_turn_5 = Game()
        self.game_turn_negative = Game()

        # values
        self.game_turn_0.turn = 0
        self.game_turn_5.turn = 5
        self.game_turn_negative = -2

    def test_get_turn(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_0.get_turn(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_5.get_turn(), 5)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            print('value error!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

but the result is not as expected, as you can see:

```
Testing started at 09:55 ...
C:\Users\oricc\PycharmProjects\practisingDrowing\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.3\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target test_canvas.TestPlayer1.test_get_turn
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_canvas.TestPlayer1.test_get_turn in C:\Users\oricc\PycharmProjects\practisingDrowing

pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
value error!

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oricc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\oricc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\oricc\PycharmProjects\practisingDrowing\test_canvas.py", line 23, in test_get_turn
    print('value error!')
  File "C:\Users\oricc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 203, in __exit__
    self._raiseFailure("{} not raised".format(exc_name))
  File "C:\Users\oricc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 135, in _raiseFailure
    raise self.test_case.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: ValueError not raised


Assertion failed

Assertion failed


Ran 1 test in 0.034s

FAILED (failures=1)

Process finished with exit code 1

Assertion failed

Assertion failed

Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

I have watched a few videos by now, read the documentation on the  [python website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises), and read a few posts. I just can get the grasp.

I mean, I can't get how to use it in my case.

Could anyone explain to me how does this work?
Thanks

Comment: You need to show the code under test. Is it actually raising a value error?

Comment: You're missing the call to `self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_negative.get_turn(), -2)` after the `assertRaises`

Comment: @DanielRoseman there is no need, a single `print('value error!')` is not going to raise a `ValueError`

Comment: @ChatterOnethank you for your comment, I have tried your code but I get the same error as 'lpox': AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_turn'

Comment: @MirkoOricci I couldn't test it obviously, the point is that with your current code you're checking if `print` will raise a ValueError and that will not happen. You need to call the function that you think will raise a ValueError

Comment: Yes, I have done it now, I was missing .turn in the set up for a negative turn. The problem is that now I don't know what to do because ValueError is not raised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `assertRaises` context manager around an operation that you expect to raise an error. If you look at your test code, can you see a line that should raise an error? I can't.

You are close - you have the general structure. But what you need is

```
def test_get_turn(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_0.get_turn(), 0)
    self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_5.get_turn(), 5)
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.game_turn_negative.get_turn()
```

I have only changed the last line. See how that is the operation that you are expecting to raise an exception?

Also, you have a bug in the `setUp` - you need to set `self.game_turn_negative.turn = -2`, not `self.game_turn_negative = -2`. Be sure to fix that too.

Now to check that the test is working, try running the test and see it pass, then change your code so that a negative turn value does *not* raise an exception, and run the test again. You should see that the test suite fails, with a complaint that a `ValueError` wasn't raise when it was expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried your code earlier, but the test fails: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_turn'.

Comment: @MirkoOricci see my edit about the bug in `setUp`, that should fix it

Comment: I missed that :P, now I get 'AssertionError: ValueError not raised'. What should I do now? write some try/except? I don't think so, because is only used in the main python file isn't it?

Comment: When do you get this AssertionError? When you run with your correct real code or when you change it so that it doesn't raise an exception? If it's your correct code, then your test suite has just shown you that your code is incorrect, well done! Now you need to fix it :-)

Comment: I guess this question has been answered. I guess it has something to do with exceptions, I am working on it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`with assertRaises` is designed around the expectation that the exception will be raised within the `with` block. In this case the only code running within the `with` block is `print('value error!')` - which will never raise a `ValueError`. This then causes the assertion to fail as a `ValueError` was not raised.

To solve your problem you'll need to adjust your application so that when an invalid condition is detected, a `ValueError` is raised. You will then be able to catch the `ValueError` inside the `assertRaises` block. It's worth noting that there appears to be a problem with your assignment to `self.game_turn_negative`. For the `game_turn_0` and `game_turn_5` values you're assigning an integer value to the `.turn` attribute, rather than the top level variable. For `game_turn_negative` you're setting it to `Game()` and then later on setting it to `-2` (rather than setting `self.game_turn_negative.turn`).

To fix your code, this may work:

```py
import unittest
from canvas import Game


class TestPlayer1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        # Game objects
        self.game_turn_0 = Game()
        self.game_turn_5 = Game()
        self.game_turn_negative = Game()

        # values
        self.game_turn_0.turn = 0
        self.game_turn_5.turn = 5
        self.game_turn_negative.turn = -2

    def test_get_turn(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_0.get_turn(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_5.get_turn(), 5)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            self.game_turn_negative.get_turn()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I get ValueError not raised. Have to fix it now

Answer (score -3):

```py
class TestPlayer1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        # Game objects
        self.game_turn_0 = Game()
        self.game_turn_5 = Game()
        self.game_turn_negative = Game()

        # values
        self.game_turn_0.turn = 0
        self.game_turn_5.turn = 5
        self.game_turn_negative = -2

    def test_get_turn(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_0.get_turn(), 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.game_turn_5.get_turn(), 5)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            print('value error!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Hi @priya_s, thanks for contributing an answer, but this is just a copy-paste of the code that was provided. You also haven't added any text to explain what you mean